# Google play snapshot sync between devices strategy

Tags: android, google-play-games, snapshot

We're using Google Play saved games services (snapshot api) to store savegames for our game in the cloud.

Besides backing up the savegames of course one of the biggest reasons we do this is being able to sync the state of the game between devices.

Now it seems that these snapshots are also coming from an on-device cache and not always from the cloud.

We're reloading the state in certain intervals and especially when the game has been running for a while there is no way to ensure that we always get the most up to date version of the snapshot.

This is especially crucial when playing on another device with the same google play account shortly after having played on the other devices.

Any best practice advice for what would be the best strategy here?

Answer (score 0):

If '*forceReload*' is set to '*true*', this call will clear any locally cached data and attemp to fetch the latest data from the server. This commonly be used for something like a user-initiated refresh. Normally, this should be set to false to gain advantages of data caching.

Link below is a useful documentation for Google APIs for Android - Snapshots: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/snapshot/Snapshots